# French for “extracurricular activities”

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, curriculum-vitae

Can we use “activités parascolaires” to interpret "extracurricular activities" in the context of a CV as it precised in the link below? Does *loisirs*, *centres d'intérêt*, *hobbies*, etc. indicate the same thing in a French CV?

https://www.reed.co.uk/career-advice/https-www-reed-co-uk-career-advice-extracurricular-activities-in-cv/

Comment: When will you learn to use quotes/italics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *activités parascolaires* are non-mandatory activities organized by a school (or by an association working in partnership with the school), outside of class hours. It is used only in the context of kindergarten, primary schools and high/secondary schools - never in universities. So the term *activités parascolaires* has a much more restricted meaning than *extracurricular activities*.

In a French CV, it is indeed rather common to add a section simply labeled *loisirs*, *centres d'intérêts* or *hobbies* (I would personally recommend to use *centres d'intérêts* as it sounds less "leisurely", but that is open to discussion).

Answer (score 1):

I use the term:

> activités extra-scolaires

That includes hobbies, sport, music, etc.

You can also find **extrascolaire**, with no hyphen.

Comment: on peut même avoir : « activités extra-professionnelles », pour le CV de quelqu'un déjà en activité.

Answer (score 0):

Même en anglais, il me semble que extra curricular activities se dit plus couramment  lorsqu’on parle du primaire ou du secondaire.